# Error in submitting form

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the tinymce as my text area on a PHP application and when I type the text directly, it is submitted without errors to MySQL. However, when I copy the text from MS Word with any other font but Calibri (Body), am getting the following error and text is not submitted:

> An error occurred .You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Calibri','sans-serif'; mso-ascii-theme-font:
>   minor-latin; mso-fareast-font-famil' at line 1

Comment: Provide more information about your question

Comment: can you show query you are executing and not only error message?

Comment: It seems you want to save unescaped string.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

When you copy pasted the text from MS Word, the formatting of the text got copied.

Hence when you pasted the same in tinymce text area, the text along with the formatting got pasted.

**Example:**

```
<p><span style="font-family: 'Calibri','sans-serif'; font-size: 14px; background-color: #f9f9f9;">Hello World!</span></p>
```

**Solution:**

Escape the string before passing it to the DB - Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

But still with the escaped string, your application is prone to SQL injection attacks. So use prepared statements.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    $text = htmlspecialchars("abc & < >");
?>
```